# Universal login python to website

Tags: python

Is possible to write a code in Python which allows you to login in every website? A single code for every kind of websites. It's very difficult because each site has own login form, so by session.post method isn't the best way.

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: you said it yourself. every site is different, so you'd need to write the code to account for every possible website you want to cater to.